# cannot declare string variable

Tags: c++, string

I cannot get my string declaration to be declared as a variable. int, double, and char all change font color, but string does not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>      // Supports use of "string" data type
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int    userInt    = 0;
   double userDouble = 0.0;
   char userChar = 0;
   string userString = 0;  // this string declaration is not being recognized
```

Comment: Please check the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/)

Comment: You don't have to initialize std::string. just `string userString;`

Comment: What is the exact compiler error that you're getting?  You should post it, so that it can be explained to you what the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: the issue is just that after I type out "string" when I try to declare it, it is not being recognized at all as a variable type. in the code above, int, double and char all change color, but string does not. the error I am getting is that "userString" has not been declared. even though i am trying to declare it, but its not being recognized as a declaration. I would try to post it but im not sure how to add more code to this chain... im very new to this...

Comment: @RachelSugg You will have to add some more code to point exactly to the position where it says it wasn't declared.

Comment: @RachelSugg -- Are these errors coming from the actual compiler, or are these errors coming from some tool (for example, Intellisense) that tries to check your errors as you type?  There is a big difference -- errors coming from the compiler are done when you actually compile your code, and these are the only "official" errors.  Errors coming from third-party tools that attempt to figure out your code as you type are **not** officially compiler errors -- they could come from bugs in the tool itself not understanding some aspect of C++.  That's why I asked you to post the actual compiler error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to default initialize the `std::string` to an empty string, you don't have to do anything. This is done by default.

```
std::string x;
std::string y = "";
```

Both will be equal.

```
x.compare(y) == 0
```

Your current intialization will not work. It WILL throw an exception during runtime.

```
std::string str = 0;
```

Please check [this example.](https://ideone.com/ODMCDq)

---

Also the "font-color" has not much to do with it being a variable or not. It all depends on the IDE / Editor you use.

- The IDE is not god
- Syntax highlighting may not work all the time
- C++ does not care if a variable is highlighted by an IDE or not

Comment: my problem doesnt have anything to do with what i am initializing string as. it has to do with the fact that "string" is not being recognized as a variable. its not changing color and when run, i get an error saying the variable "userString" has not been declared

Comment: @RachelSugg Incorrect. If you initialize the string like this `std::string x = 0` you WILL get a runtime error. Please re-check my answer regarding your "color" question. Also your program will not compile if you have somewhere a declaration issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have just realized that you haven't used quotation marks around your userString variable's value instead you should enter the string as below

```
string userString = "0";  // this string declaration is not being recognized
```

I hope this fixes your problem

Comment: the issue doesnt have anything to do with anything I type after string. as soon as i type it, it should change color showing its being recognized as a variable. it is not doing this.

Comment: Hey Rachel Sugg C++ tends to be very opinionated when it comes to data structures, example

Comment: Please read up on that, however strings, characters are all entered using quotations e.g char ed = "a"; or string dd = "Hello"; when you use your zero alone e.g string userString = 0, the C++ compiler crushes as it expects a set of characters enclosed in quotation marks, thus you can use either boolean, which uses a 1 for true and a 0 for false, e.g boolean t = 1; is the same as boolean t = true, also boolean f = 0; is the same as boolean f = false; or you can use int if you just want a number, e.g int n = 123;

Comment: @CrisShaki [...] `C++ compiler crushes as it expects a set of characters` [...] What ? The compiler crashes ? Your comment alltogether is a bit hard to decipher. It compiles fine and is valid C++. But it assumes that it is a pointer to a `char`-string, and 0 is simply a NULL-pointer (Windows defines NULL as 0). This will crash during runtime, but surely not crash the compiler.

Comment: Hey @Blacktempel apologies for that I meant the compiler might throw in an exception, however seeing that that isn't true also, you've enlightened me as well

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot to add the quotation marks " ". It is expecting a text value, not a numerical value.

```
string userString = "0"; //is correct
string userString = 0; //is incorrect
```

Another comment, just so you know the correct terminology, the code above is not just a declaration.

```
int myVal; //declaration of a variable of integer data type
int myVal = 10; //is called initialization (declaration and assignment)
```

EDIT: I've copied and pasted your code into my IDE, with the correct initialization of a string, and it works fine. I am using Codeblocks.